# SQL BETWEEN 2 date values HELP

Tags: sql, date, between

```
SELECT * FROM myDateTable 
WHERE date_Start 
OR date_end 
BETWEEN DateValue('" & CoverMonth_start & "') 
AND DateValue('" & CoverMonth_end & "')"
```

The `CoverMonth_start` and `_end` dates are looping from January to December. This query is supposed to select only the records `WHERE date_Start OR date_end BETWEEN DateValue...`. But this query is selecting all the records in the database.

Comment: you need to quote your SQL code it's unreadable

Comment: It is recommended that you use parameterized queries instead of string concatenation, to avoid "Bobby Tables attacks".  http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: lol, what a mix of english grammar and SQL syntax. Boolean logic down the drain, long live SQL as literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are doing `date_Start OR....`, this is selecting all the records that has ANY value in `date_Start` and `date_End` is in the given values range.

What you should write is this:

```
SELECT * FROM myDateTable WHERE
    date_Start BETWEEN DateValue('" & CoverMonth_start & "') AND DateValue('" & CoverMonth_end & "')"
    OR 
    date_end BETWEEN DateValue('" & CoverMonth_start & "') AND DateValue('" & CoverMonth_end & "')"
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query isn't doing what you think it is.

The `OR` is your problem - the moment the date_start is populated, that record will be returned.

This is probably the query that you want:

```
 SELECT * FROM myDateTable 
 WHERE (date_Start 
    BETWEEN DateValue('" & CoverMonth_start & "') 
    AND DateValue('" & CoverMonth_end & "')")
 OR (date_end 
    BETWEEN DateValue('" & CoverMonth_start & "') 
    AND DateValue('" & CoverMonth_end & "')")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myDateTable WHERE date_Start between date1 and date2 OR date_end BETWEEN date1 and date2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM myDateTable
WHERE (date_start BETWEEN .... AND ....)
OR
(date_end BETWEEN .... AND ....)
```

Answer (score 0):

`OR` has lower precedence than `BETWEEN`.

`WHERE date_Start OR date_end BETWEEN a AND b` translates to 
`WHERE CAST(date_Start AS BOOLEAN) = true OR ( date_end BETWEEN a AND b)`

what you want is... oh see other answers (an easy question, isnt'it?)